# Generating multiple links (URL) to display different states of my react App

Tags: reactjs, react-router, netlify

I have created a Single Page App with react and hosted it on netlify . I am making use of react-router to handle my routing. Is it possible to generate random routes (url) to send as a link for someone to view the current state of my app with a specific data ?

For Example:
 wwww.forexample.com/myappshowing5dogs
  --shows my app showing 5 dogs 
 wwww.forexample.com/myappshowing12catssandabook
 --shows my app showing a different state of my app with 12 cats and a book

How can I generate links (url) to show all the countless possible states of my app?

Comment: isn't it easier to just add a param to do that? `http://myurl.com/static-route?param=xas223xaemsr`, then based on that param you would alter your state

Comment: How do I alter my state based on a param ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`useParams`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) functionality of React-Router to do exactly that!

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, useParams} from ReactRouterDOM

const Info = () => {
  let {dogs, cats} = useParams();
  return <div>There are {dogs || 0} dogs and {cats || 0} cats</div>;
  }

const App = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route  path="/:dogs?/:cats?/"  component={Info}/>
  </BrowserRouter>)

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And to get Netlify to work nicely with these you need to add `/* /index.html 200` into your `_redirects` file.

See my demo [here](https://netlify-router-params-demo.netlify.app/5/6):
[image]

[Sourcecode](https://github.com/LukeStorry/netlify-router-params-demo) shows how to do the redirects file and Routing